# Получение Observable<List<B>> из Observable<List<A>>

Tags: kotlin, rxjava

Есть два метода:

```
fun getMovieActors(id: Long) =
    provider.retrofit
        .loadMovieCreditsById(id, WebProvider.API_KEY)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { credits ->
            credits.cast.map { it.id }
        } // в конце получаем Observable<List<Long>> (списко id актеров)

@GET("movie/{movie_id}/credits")
fun loadMovieCreditsById(@Path("movie_id") id: Long, @Query("api_key") apiKey: String): Observable<Credits>

fun getActorByID(id: Long) =
    provider.retrofit
        .loadActor(id, WebProvider.API_KEY)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .zipWith(getImageConfiguration().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())) { actor, configuration ->
            actor.also {
                it.profile_path =
                    createImageUri( configuration.images.profile_sizes[3], it.profile_path )
            }
        } // в конце получаем Observable<Actor> (конкретный актер по его id)

@GET("person/{person_id}")
fun loadActor(@Path("person_id") id: Long, @Query( "api_key") apiKey: String): Observable<Actor>
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что я хочу иметь метод, который из `List<Long>` сделает `List<Actor>` , но не могу придумать реализацию данного метода.
Возвращаемое значение должно быть именно `Observable<List<Actor>>`. (из собсветнных попыток всегда получаю в лучшем случае `Observable<Observable<List<Actor>>>`, либо Disposable)

Заранее огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
provider.retrofit
            .loadMovieCreditsById(id, WebProvider.API_KEY)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap { credits ->
                credits.cast.map { it.id }
            }
            .flatMapIterable { it }
            .flatMap { getActorByID(it)}
            .toList() // Вот здесь вы получите List<Actor>, если я все правильно понял. :)
```

Comment: Пробовал такой вариант, но боюсь что он не совсем подходит, по скольку на выходе получу  `Single<(MutableList<Actor!>..List<Actor!>?)>!`
А хочется получить именно `Observable<List<Actor>>`
Если сделать так не получится, то хотелось бы, чтобы мне на это явно указали

Answer (score 0):

```
getIds() // Observable<List<Long>>
    .flatMapSingle { ids ->
        val observables: List<Observable<Actor>> = ids.map { getActorByID(it) }
        Observable.concat(observables).toList(observables.size)
    } // Observable<List<Actor>>
```